# Htaccess issues - Redirecting from pretty url to php version

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am not a new developer and have worked with .htaccess for years, but today I'm totally stuck and have no idea what is going on. Below is my full htaccess file:

```
Options All -Indexes

ReWriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?pageurl=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?categoryurl=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&productid=$3&producturl=$4


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

website.com/category should take me to the category page which it does, but for some reason the url gets changed, as if htaccess is working in reverse, I get sent to website.com/category.php?categoryurl=category.

This is exactly the same for the other ones, my product page should be website.com/category/subcategory/123-producturl but it redirects too:

website.com/product.php/category/123-producturl?category=category&subcategory=subcategory&productid=123&producturl=producturl

Anybody have any idea at all why this is doing what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, you have not added flags to end the line in HTACCESS.

```
Options All -Indexes

ReWriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?pageurl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?categoryurl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&productid=$3&producturl=$4 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Notice [L] flag it tells the htacces to end the rule so next rule will be new one for new url

Comment: No Ahmed, unfortunately it's still doing the exact same thing. Thank you for pointing that out though, I should really always use them anyway.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to remove RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301,L] and see what it does.. I think it is redirecting the content to website.com/,,,,,,

Comment: You can also just remove the R=301 from the RewriteRule. The external redirect is forcing it to use the newly generated URL, so that is what will show up in the address bar.

Comment: Another suggestion, the above mentioned two lines should be on top of the three rules for category listing..

Comment: Yes, thank you that was the problem! I have moved that up above the other 3 rules and it is working fine now.

Comment: The issue was the RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301,L] lines. Moving them up fixed it. Thanks